# Can I record audio using the USB port on my phone?

Tags: samsung, usb-on-the-go, audio-recording

I have a mini USB 3.0 on a Samsung Galaxy Note 3.

I'm a DJ. Can I use the USB 3.0 to record music from a phono left and right output on a DJ mixer? Obviously I'd need an adapter, but is it possible?

Or would it have to be a 3.5" headphone jack connection?

Answer (score 0):

I'm no audio pro, but I'm fairly certain that something like this would require a DJ mixer that's actually made for working with Android phones, and has its own app for the phone.

Otherwise, you'd have much better luck recording over the 3.5" headphone jack.